Is it possible to run Rancher on rke2 v1.28.10? If so, which version of nginx-ingress should be used?
I installed v1.28.10+rke2r1 and have three controlplane VMs and four worker node VMs. I wanted to see if Rancher (the web service gui) would work so I added the Rancher helm repo and ran helm install rancher rancher-latest/rancher --namespace cattle-system --set hostname=cz1.tzz.zo --set replicas=3 --set bootstrapPassword=admin which ran without error.
I also installed the cert management software: helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --create-namespace --version v1.11.0
When I tried to load http://cz1.tzz.zo I received an nginx error. 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS                   RESTARTS   AGE
rancher-95d5f798-25vnj   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          3m27s
rancher-95d5f798-2fjpj   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          5m16s
rancher-95d5f798-7s75k   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          5m16s
rancher-95d5f798-9gsc7   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          2m7s
rancher-95d5f798-9v5ns   0/1     ContainerCreating        0          8s
rancher-95d5f798-bqq48   0/1     ContainerCreating        0          11s
rancher-95d5f798-dks2t   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          2m37s
rancher-95d5f798-gxxqv   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          5m16s
rancher-95d5f798-kh2jk   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          4m9s
rancher-95d5f798-qxcjh   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          3m5s
rancher-95d5f798-v9242   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   0          69s
rancher-95d5f798-x9t8n   0/1     ContainerCreating        0          47s

After waiting a few minutes for the pods to become ready I tried installing the helm chart ingress-nginx which failed. Should I try installing ingress-nginx into the rancher namespace?
helm uninstall ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "ingress-nginx": current value is "rke2-ingress-nginx"; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "ingress-nginx": current value is "kube-system"

I'd like to see if I can get the built-in ingress-nginx to work but at this point I'm not sure what is broken. Could be jetpack's cert management sw doesn't like my self-signed certs.
Any advice is welcome.
